# How to find the maximum of a multivariate function in R

Tags: r, maximize, mle

I have a joint likelihood that I need to maximize which is determined by about 25 different variables. I was hoping there was a method for finding the combination of variable values that maximized this function without resorting to 25 'for' loops that cycle through every possible value.

Here is an example of a much smaller piece of this likelihood, maximized using the 'for' loop approach, where 'temp' calculates the value of the likelihood and test is a vector that records the values of the variables used:

```
h1=23
h2=31

test=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,0)
for (N in seq(60,150,10)) {
  for (p1 in seq(0.01,1,.01)) {
    for (p2 in seq(0.01,1,.01)) {
      for (S1 in seq(0.5,1,.005)) {
        temp=factorial(N)/(factorial(h1)*factorial(h2)*factorial(N-h1-h2))*(p1)^h1*((1-p1)*S1*p2)^h2*(1-(p1+(1-p1)*S1*p2))^(N-h1-h2)
        if (temp>test[5]) test=c(p1,p2,S1,N,temp)
      }
    }
  }
}
test
```

Comment: `?optim` (but make sure to set `fnscale` argument, otherwise you will minimize by default).  You will also probably do a lot better maximizing the log of your objective function.

Comment: Thanks - that worked well for the smaller dataset, but when I try the command with the full set [optim(var,joilik,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(rep(5,10),rep(1,15),rep(-1,3),rep(0,3)),upper=c(rep(60,10),rep(50,15),rep(0,3),rep(1,3)))], I get the following error: "Error in optim(var, joilik, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(rep(5, 10),  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [26]". Any suggestions?

Comment: Using optim's `parscale` argument to make sure that the variation in all of your parameters is on the same order of magnitude may help.  You might also try `bobyqa` from the `minqa` package (which uses a derivative-free method, and also allows box constraints).